# Memory barrier use in lock-free queues

Tags: c, concurrency, 64-bit, lock-free, memory-barriers

I recently read Paul McKenney's 2010 white paper, ["Memory Barriers: a Hardware View for Software Hackers"](http://www.liblfds.org/mediawiki/images/a/a7/Michael%2C_Scott_-_Simple%2C_Fast%2C_and_Practical_Non-Blocking_and_Blocking_Concurrent_Queue_Algorithms.pdf).

I would very much appreciate some feedback / comments / guidance with regard to a small sections of C code, given below, which implement the M&S queue enqueue function, in particular with regard to memory and compiler barriers.

This code is using pointer-counter pairs to handle [ABA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem) and for the sake of this post should be considered as written for and only for x86/x64.

The inline comments are all written now, for this post, and are part of this post in that they express what I currently think I think.

For brevity, I've stripped the code of asserts and cache line padding in the structs, etc.

Currently, I think the code is quite broken, but I want to make sure I think so for the right reasons.

---

```
#define PAC_SIZE 2

struct lfds_queue_element
{
  struct lfds_queue_element
    *volatile next[PAC_SIZE];

  void
    *user_data;
};

struct lfds_queue_state
{
  struct lfds_queue_element
    *volatile enqueue[PAC_SIZE];

  struct lfds_queue_element
    *volatile dequeue[PAC_SIZE];

  atom_t volatile
    aba_counter;
};

void lfds_queue_internal_dcas_pac_enqueue( struct lfds_queue_state *lqs, struct lfds_queue_element *lqe )
{
  ALIGN(ALIGN_DOUBLE_POINTER) struct lfds_queue_element
    *local_lqe[PAC_SIZE], *enqueue[PAC_SIZE], *next[PAC_SIZE];
  unsigned char cas_result = 0;
  unsigned int backoff_iteration = 1;

  /* TRD : here we have been passed a new element to place
           into the queue; we initialize it and its next
           pointer/counter pair
  */

  local_lqe[POINTER] = lqe;
  local_lqe[COUNTER] = (struct lfds_queue_element *) lfds_abstraction_atomic_increment( &lqs->aba_counter );

  local_lqe[POINTER]->next[POINTER] = NULL;
  local_lqe[POINTER]->next[COUNTER] = (struct lfds_queue_element *) lfds_abstraction_atomic_increment( &lqs->aba_counter );

  /* TRD : now, I think there is a issue here, in that these values
           are by no means yet necessarily visible to other cores

           however, they only need to be visible once
           the element has entered the queue, and for that
           to happen, the contigious double-word CAS must
           have occurred - and on x86/x64, this carries
           with it an mfence

           however, that mfence will only act to empty our
           local store buffer - it will not cause other cores
           to flush their invalidation queues, so surely
           it can all still go horribly wrong?

           ah, but if all other cores are only accessing
           these variables using atomic operations, they
           too will be issuing mfences and so at that
           point flushing their invalidate queues
  */

  do
  {
    enqueue[COUNTER] = lqs->enqueue[COUNTER];
    enqueue[POINTER] = lqs->enqueue[POINTER];

    next[COUNTER] = enqueue[POINTER]->next[COUNTER];
    next[POINTER] = enqueue[POINTER]->next[POINTER];

    /* TRD : now, this is interesting

             we load the enqueue pointer and its next pointer
             we then (immediately below) check to see they're unchanged

             but this check is totally bogus!  we could be reading
             old values from our cache, where our invalidate queue
             has not been processed, so the initial read contains
             old data *and* we then go ahead and check from our cache
             the same old values a second time

             what's worse is that I think we could also read the correct
             values for enqueue but an incorrect (old) value for its
             next pointer...!

             so, in either case, we easily mistakenly pass the if()
             and then enter into code which does things to the queue

             now, in both cases, the CAS will mfence, which will
             cause us to see from the data structure the true
             values, but how much will that help us - we need
             to look to see what is actually being done

             the if() checks next[POINTER] is NULL

             if we have read a NULL for next, then we think
             the enqueue pointer is correcly placed (it's not
             lagging behind) so we don't need to help; we then
             try to add our element to the end of the queue

             now, it may be we have read enqueue properly but
             next improperly and so we now try to add our element
             where it will in fact truncate the queue!

             the CAS however will mfence and so at this point
             we will actually see the correct value for enqueue-next,
             and this will prevent that occurring

             if we look now at the else clause, here we have seen
             that enqueue->next is not NULL, so the enqueue pointer
             is out of place and we need to help, which we do by
             moving it down the queue

             here though we could have read enqueue correctly
             but next incorrectly; the CAS will mfence, which will
             update the cache, but since we're only comparing
             the enqueue pointer with our copy of the enqueue
             pointer, the fact our next pointer is wrong won't
             change!  so here, we move the enqueue pointer to
             some old element - which although it might be in the
             queue (so this would be an inefficiency, you'd have
             to do a bunch more queue walking to get the enqueue
             pointer to the final element) it might not be, too!
             it could in the meantime have been dequeued and
             that of course would be death
    */

    if( lqs->enqueue[POINTER] == enqueue[POINTER] and lqs->enqueue[COUNTER] == enqueue[COUNTER] )
    {
      if( next[POINTER] == NULL )
      {
        local_lqe[COUNTER] = next[COUNTER] + 1;
        cas_result = lfds_abstraction_atomic_dcas_with_backoff( (atom_t volatile *) enqueue[POINTER]->next, (atom_t *) local_lqe, (atom_t *) next, &backoff_iteration );
      }
      else
      {
        next[COUNTER] = enqueue[COUNTER] + 1;
        lfds_abstraction_atomic_dcas( (atom_t volatile *) lqs->enqueue, (atom_t *) next, (atom_t *) enqueue );
      }
    }
  }
  while( cas_result == 0 );

  local_lqe[COUNTER] = enqueue[COUNTER] + 1;

  lfds_abstraction_atomic_dcas( (atom_t volatile *) lqs->enqueue, (atom_t *) local_lqe, (atom_t *) enqueue );

  return;
}
```

Comment: http://www.liblfds.org/mediawiki/images/a/a7/Michael%2C_Scott_-_Simple%2C_Fast%2C_and_Practical_Non-Blocking_and_Blocking_Concurrent_Queue_Algorithms.pdf

Comment: Are the comments/observations, in the comments in the code, correct?

Comment: [Slide deck of paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a46d/801658200b957dcdcfda80d38d53a9796f2e.pdf)

Comment: Actually, it seems like the (broken) linked paper is different then the named paper; [this is a working link to Paul McKenney's paper](http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/scalability/paper/whymb.2010.06.07c.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

CAS is atomic, so if one thread succeeds while another thread tries, the other thread will fail and try again.

It only works if all threads try to access the same memory with the same mechanism, that is, they all access with CAS. If they don't, the guarantees associated with CAS (in this case, memory fences) go out the window.

Comment: CAS itself, e.g. the compare-exchange instruction, *does not fail*.  It has no error return.  The CAS operation can "fail" from the point of view of the algorithm, in that the operation which was desired could not operate as another processor modified the data involved after it was read by the current processor but before the CAS operation occurred.  In this queue algorithm, there are non-lock-prefixed (lock in the sense of x86/x64 assembly) reads.

Comment: These are reads only so they require only a memory barrier; there is I think no need to lock the cache line (a la CAS (and indeed, how couuld you, given there is no atomic read).  The question is, what memory barries are required where?

Comment: @BlankXavier, it would help to show `lfds_queue_internal_dcas_pac_enqueue`. But in general, you need to have a write-release barrier before you enqueue, and a read-acquire barrier after you successfully dequeue.

Comment: That function is a direct wrapper for the atomic CAS operation.  It does nothing else except assert its arguments (I changed it to a macro yesterday in fact).